# getDownloadUrl in firebase android not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

First I take image from the user using a crop activity, I compress it and create a thumb image. I upload them on storage and save their download url in the database. For some reason, image is uploaded and link is retrieved but the thumb_image is uploaded but no link is retrieved. Please help me out. What am I doing wrong?

```
mprogbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
mylay.setClickable(false);
Uri resultUri= result.getUri();
final File thumb_filePath = new File(resultUri.getPath());
Bitmap thumb_bitmap = new Compressor(SettingsActivity.this).
        setMaxWidth(200)
        .setMaxHeight(200)
        .setQuality(75)
        .compressToBitmap(thumb_filePath);

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
thumb_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
final byte[] thumb_byte = baos.toByteArray();

final StorageReference filepath = mstore.child("profile_pictures").child(mcurrentuser+".jpg");
final StorageReference thumbfilepath = mstore.child("profile_pictures").child("thumbs").child(mcurrentuser+".jpg");


filepath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
        if(task.isSuccessful())
        {
            final String[] downloadurl = {""};
            filepath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    downloadurl[0] =uri.toString();
                }
            });

            thumbfilepath.putBytes(thumb_byte).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> thumb_task) {



                    if(thumb_task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        final String[] thumb_downloadurl = {""};
                        thumbfilepath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                thumb_downloadurl[0] =uri.toString();
                            }
                        });
                        Map mymap= new HashMap();
                        mymap.put("image", downloadurl[0]);
                        mymap.put("thumb_image", thumb_downloadurl[0]);
                        mdatabase.updateChildren(mymap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if(task.isSuccessful())
                                {
                                    mprogbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    mylay.setClickable(true);
                                    Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this,"Profile Picture updated",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mprogbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        mylay.setClickable(true);
                        Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this,"Profile Picture could not be updated",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });


        }
        else
        {
            mprogbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
```

thumb_downloadurl[0] is just an empty string

Comment: Use `continueWithTask` to return the download url and imlement `addOnCompleteListener` on it to get the downloaded `url`

Answer (score 0):

Getting the download URL is an asynchronous operation. When you call `getDownloadUrl()` the Firebase SDK *starts* getting the download URL from the servers. When it as retrieved the download URL, it calls your `onSuccess` method.

While it's waiting, Firebase lets your code outside the `onSuccess` callback continue, as Android would otherwise show an "Application Not Responding" dialog. This is when your code with `mymap.put("image", downloadurl[0])` runs, and at that point the download URL hasn't been returned from the server yet.

Any code that needs access to the download URL needs to be (called from) **inside** the `onSuccess` method. So something like this:

```
thumbfilepath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
        thumb_downloadurl[0] =uri.toString();

        Map mymap= new HashMap();
        mymap.put("image", downloadurl[0]);
        mymap.put("thumb_image", thumb_downloadurl[0]);
        mdatabase.updateChildren(mymap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    mprogbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    mylay.setClickable(true);
                    Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this,"Profile Picture updated",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

There are quite a lot of things you can do with the `Task` API that you're using here. I recommend reading Doug's series of [blog posts on becoming a task master](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/09/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-1.html).